# Multiple keys created instead of one key in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Here I am trying to create 10 seconds bucket for incoming UDP packets using packet arrival time, but always creates multiple keys for within 10 seconds after removing.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String> tenSecondBucket =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String>();
```

This thread tries to write into hash map continuously. When adding new entry it compares the old entry by key (timestamp), whether older than 10 seconds, if yes, then create new Entry, otherwise it will update it.

```java
Thread writingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);

                if(tenSecondBucket.size() > 0) {
                    // getting last key
                    long lastKey = 0;
                    for (long keyValue : tenSecondBucket.keySet()) {
                        lastKey = keyValue;
                    }

                    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastKey > 10000) {
                        tenSecondBucket.put(System.currentTimeMillis(), "secondEntry");
                    } else {
                        tenSecondBucket.put(lastKey, "updatedEntry");
                    }
                } else {
                    tenSecondBucket.put(System.currentTimeMillis(), "newEntry");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});

writingThread.start();
```

This thread removes the 10 seconds older keys.

```java
Thread removingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);

                if(tenSecondBucket.size() > 0) {
                    tenSecondBucket.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
                        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - key > 10000) {
                            tenSecondBucket.remove(key);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});

removingThread.start();
```

This thread tries to read what is happening there.

```java
Thread readingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);

                if(tenSecondBucket.size() > 0) {
                    tenSecondBucket.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
                        System.out.println("testing key which is timestamp " + key);
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});

readingThread.start();

}
```

Comment: `for (long keyValue : tenSecondBucket.keySet()) {  
                        lastKey = keyValue;  
                    }`  
  
In this code keySet it not ordered, it will get you a random key not the last one you used.  

Change  
`tenSecondBucket.put(System.currentTimeMillis(), "newEntry");`  to `lastkey = System.currentTimeMillis();  
tenSecondBucket.put(lastkey, "newEntry");`

I don't know how to format a comment so it is readable.

Comment: @SteveBauer If multiple threads try to write, then I cant store last key like you described.

Comment: That is true, 
`for (long keyValue : tenSecondBucket.keySet()) {
      if(keyValue > lastKey)  lastKey = keyValue;
}` would work

Comment: yea but still here race condition problem occurs. I don't know how to solve this problem when I am trying to create a 10second bucket using current milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steve said in comments, your approach to get last key is incorrect and will result in random value.

You also mentioned in comments that you need this to be thread-safe for multiple writer threads.

I'd try something like the following, using a shared `AtomicLong` to save the "last key", and update it atomically with [`updateAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#updateAndGet-java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator-):

```
    AtomicLong lastKey = new AtomicLong();
    Thread writingThread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long localLastKey = lastKey.updateAndGet(oldValue -> oldValue < now - 10000 ? now : oldValue);
                if (localLastKey == now) {
                    tenSecondBucket.put(now, "newEntry");
                } else {
                    tenSecondBucket.put(localLastKey, "updatedEntry@" + now);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```